# Create random binary sequences with last and first element equal to 1

Tags: matlab, random

I use  `rand(1,N)<=0.5`in order to create binary sequences with 1s, and 0s.

N can take any value from 0 and above.

What I want to achieve is to have the same functionality as above but secure that always first and last elements will be 1.

For example

### For N=0 --> empty array

### For N=1 -->[ 1 ]

### For N=2 -->[ 1 1 ]

### For N=3 --> [1 0 1] or [1 1 1]

### For N=4 --> [1 0 0 1] or [1 0 1 1] or [1 1 0 1] or [1 1 1 1]

and you see the logic??  Is there any automated way to achieve this?? For N=2 and above I guess `[1 rand(1,N-2)<=0.5 1]` works, but I want something that also works for N=0 and N=1;

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the clearest way would be something like

```
switch N
case 0
    result = [];
case 1
    result = 1;
otherwise
    result = [1 rand(1,N-2)<=0.5 1];
end
```

But that's *boring*, isn't it? So how about this?

```
result = rand(1,N)<.5;
result(mod(1:end, end)<=1) = 1;
```

Comment: Actually you could remove `case 2` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the representation of decimal numbers:

```
odd = (randi(2^(N-2)) + 2^(N-2)) * 2 - 1;    % random odd number
de2bi(odd, 'left-msb')
```